# Checking the loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int lop, squr;
    for (lop=1; lop<=20; lop=lop+1);
    {
        squr = lop*lop;
        printf("%5d,%5d,\n",lop,squr);
    }
    getch();
}
```

my friend is saying is that this source code is working well.. but it is not working well at my side. what should I have to do to work well in C++ .

My Friend is saying to me that above mentioned code is working well in the version which he is using. I said, this code is incorrect and will give execution errors.... is above mentioned code is correct for any standard or version of C / C++.

and Also tell me that how many versions C++ are available...

Regards

Comment: What do you mean by "not working well"? As for the versions of C++, I found them in the Wikipedia C++ article before the table of contents in less than a minute, just saying.

Comment: It's not working well because of `void main()`.

Comment: This is C, not C++. So why is it tagged as such?

Comment: Could be MSVC complaining about `getch`...

Comment: `<conio.h>` is specific to Windows. On Linux you'll want to learn using the `ncurses` library.

Comment: My Friend is saying to me that above mentioned code is working well in the version which he is using. I said, this code is incorrect and will give execution errors.... is above mentioned code is correct for any standard or version of C / C++.

Comment: @chris can you please explain it.. the 5th Point

Comment: @AbdullahMuhammadUmar, If you mean the `getch`, MSVC insists you use `_getch` instead.

Comment: @chris I am not using MSVC but I am using borland C++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`for (lop=1; lop<=20; lop=lop+1);` is the problem. Change to `for (lop=1; lop<=20; lop=lop+1)` (remove the semicolon will make this work).

This is your code, with problem fixed and optimized:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h> // Remove if you want

int main() {
    clrscr(); // Remove if you want
    int lop, squr;
    for (lop=1; lop<=20; ++lop) {
        squr = lop*lop;
        printf("%5d,%5d,\n", lop, squr);
    }
    getch(); // Remove if you want
    return 0;
}
```

Lines with `// Remove if you want` can be removed, but will change the behaviour. See @VinayakGarg's comment.

Comment: void main is still not standard C or C++

Comment: @ÖöTiib Changed. But `<conio.h>`, `clrscr()` and `getch()` are hard to get rid of without changing the behaviour.

Comment: @xiaomao: The only change would be (on Turbo C++), screen showing previous output, and new user complaining, "why is the output not coming?" ;)

Comment: But I just Want to know that why it is not working on dev C++

Comment: @Abdullah Most likely the MinGW compiler used doesn't have the header `<conio.h>`. In that case, remove the lines marked `// Remove if you want`.

Comment: @xiaomao I got your words. thanks

Answer (score 6):

This is how it should be -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int lop, squr;
    for (lop = 1; lop <= 20; lop++)
    {
        squr = lop*lop;
        printf("%5d,%5d,\n", lop, squr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`conio.h` and hence `clrscr()` and `getch()` are not part of standard, you **should not use** them in your code.

**EDIT-**

> and Also tell me that how many versions C++ are available...

C++ doesn't have versions exactly, there are [standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_14882#Standardization)

```
Year    C++ Standard                    Informal name
2011    ISO/IEC 14882:2011              C++11
2007    ISO/IEC TR 19768:2007           C++TR1
2003    ISO/IEC 14882:2003              C++03
1998    ISO/IEC 14882:1998              C++98
```

However there are versions of C++ compiler like [gcc 4.7.2](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/) etc.

Comment: Maybe it's written for Borland Turbo C.

Comment: @0605002: This is what I immediately thought :) But above code will work on it as well.

Comment: I wish that, that dinosaur IDE is removed from the old machines of schools and universities.

Comment: Ooh, I hadn't noticed GCC 4.7.2 came out. Thanks :)

Comment: Exactly, I am looking for. I got my answer.. Thanks @VinayakGarg